# Wordpress―run JS after Widget was created in Admin panel

Tags: widget, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a Wordpress Theme that includes a custom Widget, everything works out fine but there is one thing I do not know how to implement correctly:

I would like to run some Javascript after the Widget Instance was created in the admin panel, that means in the very moment after the widget was dropped in a sidebar, not after saving.

I have no Problems with running JS after the page was loaded or the Widget was saved, I want to run Javascript after the User just dropped a new Instance into the side bar, what actually can happen more than once without page reload.

Greetings philipp

Answer (score 1):

Place a script tag in the widget form function.

```
function form($instance)
{
?><script type="text/javascript">console.log("firing javascript");</script>
<?php
//form details...

}
```

I eventually went a different way with this. Loaded our plugin admin script on the page using wp_enque_script and then just used jquery selectors and an event handler to target the right widget.

```
$('div.widgets-sortables')
                .on('sortstop', function (event, ui) {
                    // only if this widget has the proper identifier...do something
                    if (ui.item.find('.my_widget').length == 0)
                        return;
                    run some function...
```

Still not my favourite technique...but it is cleaner then coding it in the widget. Does require a variable to track created widgets and using the "this" variable is useful

Comment: This seems to be the only way I've gotten working thus far, though it seems like there has to be a better way to do it...

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this I just figured out --

I'm going to show a more complex example involving dependencies, though realise the bit in `Custom_Widget::form()` is the real answer to the question:

```
function add_js_deps() {
  if (is_admin()) {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-accordion');
  } 
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_js_deps' ); // "init" because wp_enqueue_scripts is too late.

// Then in the widget....
class Custom_Widget extends WP_Widget {
  public function form($instance) {
    /** Collapsing accordion-y form HTML here **/
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-js', plugins_url('js/my.js', __FILE__), array('jquery-ui-accordion'), '1.0.0', true);
  }
}
```

I'd argue this is the better route as it has dependency management and you won't have a bunch of JavaScript mid-way into your DOM. Using [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) is generally always the more WordPressian way of doing things regardless.